# "Xcode cannot run using the selected device" iPhone 4 with iOS7 and Xcode 5.02

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

So I get the "Xcode cannot run.." pop up. "Choose a destination with a supported architecture in order to run on this device".

This happens when I try to run with on an **iPhone 4 that has iOS7.0.4** using Xcode 5.02

Build settings on target:

```
Architectures: $(ARCHS_STANDARD) armv7, armv7s
Build Active Architecture Only: NO
Valid Architectures: arm64 armv7 armv7s
```

I really can't believe Xcode hasn't made this stuff easier over time.

Note: I also tried adding armv6 to the list just to test. No dice.

**EDIT: Got it working, will update this soon with final settings.**

Comment: Have you tried removing the arm64 from the list of valid architectures? Or adding it to the list of architectures. I've had a similar problem before, but cannot remember how I solved it.

Comment: Just tried that, no dice. If you have a project in Xcode 5.02 that runs on iPhone 4 with iOS7, then post your settings.

Comment: Restart the phone, restart Xcode. Try again.

Comment: @Adis also since I want the app to run on the iPhone 5s as well, why would I remove arm64?

Comment: Can you also put your Project settings ?

Comment: It's not so much removing as much as tinkering trying to figure out where is the issue exactly. Are your project settings same as your Target settings?

Comment: Stupid question:  You're not building for iPad only, are you?

Comment: @HotLicks no not building for iPad only.

Comment: @Coche, ok I think you are onto something. Let me cross check my project vs target settings.

Comment: Ok, it is running !! thanks all. Still not 100% sure which of my edits did it. I removed arm64 in the target architecture. I will update the question with final config.